# How to keep SSIS variable static during the package execution

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have a SSIS package which reads from the MSSQL database and saves it into a xlsx file.

I dynamically change the extract with the following format: [filename - ddmmyyyy hhmm].xlsx

problems is this: my SSIS package creates a file like [filename - 18052021 1400].xlsx

however when it tries to email it for example, the time is now 1401 and it tries to find a file name like  [filename - 18052021 1401].xlsx which does not exist and so it generates an error.

Is there any way to keep the variable static through the execution?

Many thanks,

Comment: I really like @billinkc's solution, but the way I solved this is to pass getdate() into a datetime parameter with SQL. It is calculated before the job starts so it stays static.

Comment: Seems like you can set a variable once with a script task as well

Comment: that is a very good advice, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is that every time a variable with an Expression is read, it is evaluated. I [vent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29918029/ssis-2008-get-current-date-in-variables/29921654#29921654) about this from [time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458910/leading-zero-with-datestamp-in-ssis-expression/28459183#28459183) to [time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754766/ssis-variable-expression-using-time-in-two-places/34754852#34754852) in my answers because it can be an insidious little problem to track down.

Currently, you are building a file name something like

```
"FileName - " + (DT_WSTR, 2) day(getdate()) ...
```

The problem as I've already hinted and you're experiencing is that every time that expression is evaluated, SSIS checks the current time. If your package runs for more than a minute, you'll have crossed the boundary and now have a "new" name to deal with.

The way to resolve it, is to use a System scoped variable, `@[System::StartTime]`, instead of the `getdate`

```
"FileName - " + (DT_WSTR, 2) day(@[System::StartTime])) ...
```

StartTime is the time the package itself starts. It could run for a minute or a day and the value will remain constant because it's what you expect - the time the package started.

If you need something that *can* change but remains constant for a specific scope, put all the pieces in a Sequence Container and then you can make use of a System scoped variable named (approximately) ContainerStartTime. The container (sequence, foreach, for) only has one start time but it can be 10 minutes later than the package itself started.

Comment: Many many thanks my friend :) helped me out alot!

Comment: Sadly for me it seems the System::StartTime changes during running the package, it's very VERY weird. I have a variable StringStartDateTimeStamp which is an expression which converts System::StartTime to yyyymmdd_hhmiss. And I have it set as a caption so I can check it during running, but also in a filename for a backup (which is build through an expression which uses the variable) but the seconds are 4 seconds later. So for some reason StartTime does not work properly in all cases.

Comment: @SuperDre I have not experienced that. If you have a minimal reproduction, I'd be delighted to see it. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-variables?view=sql-server-ver15) calls out that it is the time the package started to run but there can always be corner cases.

Comment: @billinkc Variable **StartDateTimeStamp** expr: `(DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(@[System::StartTime]) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(@[System::StartTime]), 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY(@[System::StartTime]), 2) + "_" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("HH",@[System::StartTime]), 2)  + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mi",@[System::StartTime]), 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("ss",@[System::StartTime]), 2)`. Caption of seqcontainer uses variable, also a variable for filename which is used in a query for backup. Seconds of caption has 4 sec diff (cap part of validating first? and filename execute?).

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your variable's value is an expression then, not a Value? If so, then don't use an Expression for the variable, assign it a value, and then assign a new value of the variable at the start of your SSIS package using a expression Task. Without the variable name, nor your expression, I can't give the exact solution, but the expression task would have an expression like:

```cs
@[User::YourVariableName] = {Your original Expression}
```